# Bring up numpad board on mobile and ipad

Tags: ipad, html, android-layout

Im developing a mobile site and on my  I want the numpad to appear when users get to this field. Is it even possible to make a  transform to ipad and android numpad? ..

I have checked with a friend who tells me that my fields are called from a database and they are called as a size field?

Hope anyone can give me some hints

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
   <input type="number" />
```

Comment: Hi Adam, unfortnually that dosent work.
My input field is calling data to database: here is the code:
echo '<td class="smalltop" valign="top">Antal<br><input type="number" name="add_id['.$number_of_products.']"  id="add_id_'.$products_id.'" min="1" max="5" value="1" size="3"></td>';

If I delete app id it works great, but with the id it wont work.